# How to fix multiply and cast of complex type?

Tags: c++

I have a template class that applies gain to a vector. The template must handle int, float and complex float types. Here is my MWE:

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

template<class T> class Star
{
public:
    void applyGain(std::vector<T> &data)
    {
        double g =  2.0;  // Gain

        for (unsigned i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
        {
            data[i] *= g;
        }
    }
};

Star<float> floatStar;
Star<std::complex<float>> complexStar;

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> floatVec = { 1.0, 2.0 };
    std::vector<std::complex<float>> complexFloatVec = { (1.0f,-1.0f) };

    floatStar.applyGain(floatVec);
    complexStar.applyGain(complexFloatVec);

    return 0;
}
```

The code builds fine as is, however, it gives a compiler warning:

```
warning C4244: '*=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
```

For the float case, this is easily fixed by changing the for loop to:

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
{
    data[i] = static_cast<T>(g * data[i]);
}
```

However, the complex case then fails:

```
error C2784: 'std::complex<_Other> std::operator *(const std::complex<_Other> &,const _Ty &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::complex<_Other> &' from 'double'
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: The problem is that floating point specialisations of `std::complex` require explicit conversions if the precision is being reduced.   Your code, to work, requires conversions that reduce precision to be implicit - which they aren't.     Since you're fighting a specific provision in the standard, the simplest way is to explicitly specialise your template for the complex types, using the fact that `complex<X>::value_type` gives the type of `X` to get `g` of a required type.   You won't be able to write a single templated function that works for all possible types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.0` and `2.0` are literals of type `double`, and `g` is a `double` too.

If you want to suppress the compiler warnings, use either

1. `1.f` and `2.f` for `float` literals. And a `float` type for `g`.
2. Use `double` rather than `float` in your templates.

These days, I'd plump for (2) which could end up faster on modern chipsets. If you can change `Star`, then you could write

```
T g = static_cast<T>(2);  // Gain
```

and also, use `std::size_t` rather than `unsigned` as the type for `i`, or for real pedantry: `std::vector<T>::size_type`.

Comment: Well, depends on it's CPU or GPU ;)

Comment: @Lingxi: Hence "could" and "modern". Folk using `float` as an optimisation need to check they are not actually causing harm.

Comment: I'm sorry, I showed the wrong warning message. I've now edited my question and shown the correct one.  The warning refers to the line in the for loop. I think I have initialised the vectors correctly in main().

Comment: @DavidA: Answer still holds. You're mixing `float` and `double` types. Pick one, and stick to it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It's used in legacy code and must cope with complex float and complex double.

Comment: @DavidA: But you asked how to fix it. If you're not allowed to fix it then the only thing you can really do is switch off the warning.

Comment: @DavidA If you can't touch the code, why bother about any warnings?

Comment: @PasserBy: It defies logic doesn't it? Asking "How to fix" then saying "Unfortunately I can't".

Comment: I can change the class but not the users of the class.  I think that is not an unreasonable position :-)

Comment: @DavidA: Very well, if you can change `Star` then see the new bit in my answer.